# LinkedList Move last element to first element

Tags: java, queue

I made linkedlist with queue, but I need help for one method

```
public class QueueLinkedList{
private Node first;
private Node last;
public QueueLinkedList(){
   first = null;
   last = null;
}

class Node{
   public Object data;
   public Node next;
}
    ...
public void lastToFirst(){
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.data = last.data;
   newNode.next = first;
   first = newNode;
   last = null;
}
```

I added "1","2","3","4", and called lastToFirst,

and printed.

my expected value was 4123

but It gave me 41234.

How could I remove the last value 4?

Comment: even if you set last to null (which does not make sense either, the new last would be the former last but one...), the last but one node will still have reference to the `4` node in the `next` field

Answer (score 1):

Either make it a double-linked-list by introducing a `public Node prev;` to the `Node` class and doing a `last.prev.next = null` or do a linear scan starting at `first`, searching for the node with `node.next == last` and change that node's `next` attribute to null.